# Adding Possibly Nil Values

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to write a function in ruby that sums up the parameters, however, if any of the parameters are null, it will skip that parameter and continue (unless all the values are nil, in which case it will return nil)

```
def sum(*vals)
  sum = nil
  vals.each do |val|
    value = eval(val)
    unless value.nil?
      sum.nil? ? sum = value : sum += value
    end
  end

  sum
end
```

The issue is that the parameters themselves are being sent in such a way that their evaluation might cause a nil error (i.e. the input is something like '2-nil').  If this happens I don't want it to break, but continue adding.

So in other words, add all the parameters, and if there is a nil value or a nil error in the parameter, skip it and continue adding.

So I've come up with two possible solutions.

1. Delay evaluation of the parameters by shielding them with quotes and eval-ing them within the function so I can catch these errors and continue working through the parameters.  However this shielding is rather messy and gets particularly messy with nested quotes.  I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to delay evaluation of parameters?
2. Locally override/create addition, subtraction, etc methods for the nilclass, such that those errors in the parameter don't cause errors, but instead produce nil.  However I am unsure how to override/create those methods for the nilclass, let alone to limit its use to not occur in the entire project.

If anyone has any insight into those options or any other options, it would be a great help!

edit:  an example input might be

```
bob = 2
fred = 3
tom = nil
john = nil

sum(bob, fred+tom, john) => 2
```

Because fred+tom causes and error, which I'd like to result in nil.

At the moment my solution is

```
def sum(*vals)
    sum = nil
    vals.each do |val|
      begin
        value = eval(val)
        unless value.nil?
          sum.nil? ? sum = value : sum += value
        end
      rescue TypeError, NoMethodError
        nil
      end
    end
    sum
end

sum('bob', 'fred+tom', 'john') => 2
```

However I'd like to not have to shield every input

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the possible input? You said "something like '2-nil'" but I'm not really sure what you're saying there. Is that "two minus nil?"

Comment: This question begs for an example. What does "null" mean?

Comment: Apologies all, an example has been added!

Comment: "`nil` error" is meaningless. `eval('2-nil')` raises the exception `"TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum"`.  Using `eval` in this way raises a red flag. It's OK as long as you are certain it could not do something, er, bad, like sending compromising photos to everyone on your mailing list. Still, I'd avoid it if you can.

Comment: That is my current solution (actually just updated it to reflect that as you said that) however, I'd ideally like to not have to shield every parameter in quotes

Comment: All you need to do is change `value = eval(val)` to `value = eval(val) rescue nil`. An alternative to `sum.nil? ? sum = value : sum += value` is `(sum ||= 0) += value`.

Comment: My goal however is to not need to shield every individual input

Comment: You changed your question in such a way that it makes my comment that includes `eval(val) rescue nil` meaningless. That's one reason there's a SO rule that questions are not to be changed.

Comment: Regarding "I'd ideally like to not have to shield every parameter in quotes.", that's problematic because `2-nil` raises the exception `TypeError: `nil` can't be coerced into `Fixnum` before `eval(2-nil)` is evaluated. You'd need something like `eval(2-nil rescue nil) rescue nil`.

Comment: I sincerely apologize if my question and edits were unclear, still new to stack overflow dos and don'ts

Answer (score 0):

I got that your input is an array obtained by a string like this `'2-nil-3.5-nil-1-0-10-nil'`. 
If so, and if the input array is not so big, you can do easily something like

```
def sum(*vals)
  vals.map { |val| eval(val) }.compact.inject(:+)
end
```

Obviously in this case you might compact the array before pass it to this function and so you can avoid `eval` easily.

Comment: Change `eval(val)` to `eval(val) rescue nil` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked best for my specific situation was monkeypatching/refining specific methods to account for possibly nil values, and mixing it into the file that performed these calculations.

Again, this is my very specific case in which the syntax needed to closely resemble a certain style.

Many thanks all!